# Banach space and its closed subspace. a vectors satisfying inequality.

Tags: inequality, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

*V*=a Banach space over **R**

*W*=a proper closed subspace of *V*

Prove : For any $\epsilon > 0$, there is a *v* $\in$_V_ such that ||*v*||=1 and ||*v*+*w*||$\geq$ $1$ - $\epsilon$

I have shown that there exists such *v* $\in$ *V* such that ||*v*||=$1$

But I am having a trouble to show that ||*v*||=1 and ||*v*+*w*||$\geq$ $1$ - $\epsilon$

I was trying to use the fact that such *v* with ||*v*||=$1$ are the vectors on the unit sphere. But I do not know how to proceed with this idea.

So any ideas and opinions would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%27s_lemma

Answer (score 0):

Let $y \in V \setminus W$ with $\def\norm#1{\left\|#1\right\|}\norm y = 1$. Then, as $W$ is closed $d := \def\dist{\mathop{\rm dist}}\dist(y, W) > 0$. Choose $\delta > 0$ such that $\frac{d}{d+ \delta} > 1-\epsilon$. There is some $w \in W$ with $\norm{y-w} < d + \delta$. We let $v := \frac{y-w}{\norm{y-w}}$. Then $\norm v = 1$ and 
$$ \dist(v,W) = \dist\left(\frac{y-w}{\norm{y-w}}, W\right)
   = \frac 1{\norm{y-w}} \dist(y-w, W) = \frac 1{\norm{y-w}}\dist(y,W)
   > \frac{\dist(y,W)}{d+\delta} = \frac{d}{d+\delta} > 1-\epsilon.
$$

Comment: How do we know that dist(_y_ - _w_ / || _y_ - _w_ ||, _W_) is equal to (1/|| _y_ - _w_ || ) dist (_y_ - _w_ , _W_ ) ?

Comment: Because $W$ is a subspace and for $w' \in W$
$$ \| (y-w)/\|y-w\| - w' \| = \frac 1{\|y-w\|} \cdot \| (y-w) - \|y-w\|w' \|. $$